# deep-learning on Matlab with AMD graphic cards

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, ati

how can I run [this example](http://it.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/image-category-classification-using-deep-learning.html) in my pc? I don't have Nvidia graphic cards so I cannot use Cuda in Matlab.

I need to do it with Matlab because half of the my code is written in Matlab and all variables are in Matlab format.

My PC has ATI Radeon HD 4530 graphic card.

I read [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_deep_learning_software), but it is still confusing to understand which one is suitable.

Update1: I want to Train a deep neural network for image classification. A task similar to [this example](http://it.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/image-category-classification-using-deep-learning.html).

Update2: When I run the code mentioned in Update1, it gives me following error:

```
There is a problem with the CUDA driver or with this GPU device. Be sure that you have a supported GPU and that the
latest driver is installed.

Error in nnet.internal.cnn.SeriesNetwork/activations (line 48)
            output = gpuArray(data);

Error in SeriesNetwork/activations (line 269)
                YChannelFormat = predictNetwork.activations(X, layerID);

Error in DeepLearningImageClassificationExample (line 262)
trainingFeatures = activations(convnet, trainingSet, featureLayer, ...

Caused by:
    The CUDA driver could not be loaded. The library name used was 'nvcuda.dll'. The error was:
    The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: I am sure it can be done, but I don't understand what you want to do. What library are you planning to use? Does it support Open CL? Do you need GPU acceleration? Would running it on the CPU only be an alternative?

Comment: I want to Train a deep neural network for image classification. A task similar to this example: http://it.mathworks.com/help/nnet/examples/training-a-deep-neural-network-for-digit-classification.html?searchHighlight=deep%20learning

Comment: I don't have any specific library in mind, I just like to make it run in Matlab. I dont need GPU acceleration (but can be good if it works :-) )

Comment: I changed the link to other matlab's example which is more suitable

Comment: As suggested, I asked the question about running the code separately : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310280/how-to-force-matlab-to-run-a-deep-learning-code-on-cpu-instead-of-gpu

Comment: MATLAB only supports NVIDIA GPUs. The only other option would be to write the GPU code yourself and compile with MEX, but anything MATLAB does (`gpuArray`) will only work with NVIDIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MatConvNet](http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/quick/) ->
[Work both on CPU and GPU](http://6.869.csail.mit.edu/fa15/lecture/tutorial_matconvnet.pdf).

**MatConvNet** is a MATLAB toolbox implementing Convolutional Neural Networks (CNNs) for computer vision applications. It is simple, efficient, and can run and learn state-of-the-art CNNs. Many pre-trained CNNs for image classification, segmentation, face recognition, and text detection are available.

Another option: [Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org) in general and [Openmp variant of caffe](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/439) in particular support Matlab and work both on CPU and GPU

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You will have to create DLL's and use OpenCL. Look into S-Functions and Mex.

Check [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html)

There are third party tools that you may be able to use. I personally have never tried it.

[Possible Tool](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_there_a_solution_to_interface_OpenCL_with_MATLAB)

Comment: Why S-Functions? As far as I understand no Simulink is involved here.

Comment: Look into mex functions then :)

Comment: thanks for answer. I don't know how much effort it needs to apply your solution. I am loooking for an easy to perform and understand solution( same discussion you have [in your website](http://www.makketronix.com/sites/default/files/inline-images/UnitSquare_1.png). I tried to ask my question in different way (refer to update2 inside my question): how you run matlab example with your method?

Comment: Ah, I see. I don't think that Mathworks support OpenCL at this point. They list NVIDIA GPU as hardware requirements. I will update my answer to a possible third party tool.