# How do I force MATLAB to run deep learning code on the CPU instead of the GPU?

Tags: matlab, compilation, deep-learning

I don't have [CUDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA)-enabled Nvidia GPU, and I want to force MATLAB to run the code on CPU instead of GPU (yes, I know, it will be very very slow). How can I do it?

As an example, let’s try to run [this code](http://it.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/image-category-classification-using-deep-learning.html) on my PC without CUDA. Here is the error given by MATLAB:

```
There is a problem with the CUDA driver or with this GPU device. Be sure that you have a supported GPU and that the latest driver is installed.

Error in nnet.internal.cnn.SeriesNetwork/activations (line 48) 
output = gpuArray(data); 

Error in SeriesNetwork/activations (line 269) 
YChannelFormat = predictNetwork.activations(X, layerID); 

Error in DeepLearningImageClassificationExample (line 262) 
trainingFeatures = activations(convnet, trainingSet, featureLayer, ... 

Caused by: 
The CUDA driver could not be loaded. The library name used was 'nvcuda.dll'. The error was: 
The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: AFAIK, after you do the conversion `output = gpuArray(data)`, operations that manipulate the `output` will be done on the GPU. So I'd start by removing the conversion, i.e. replace it with `output=data;` and see how the program behaves after that.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3087361/103167 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/21946701/103167

Comment: Make the first line after the function definition "keyboard" this will pause the function execution and give you access to your keyboard, now run each line one after the other such that you can see what works and what fails. However I do also suspect that mkfin comment is what you are looking for. Alternatively use a CUDA emulator as suggested by Ben Voigt.

Comment: tnx @BenVoigt for links. now the question is which method is applicable in Matlab?

Comment: You can't. If you understand the very basic prociples of programming you willbe aware that code to work on A does not work on B. Code designed to run on GPUs can not run on CPUs as it is, unless rewritten.

Comment: @AnderBiguri If you understand basic of programming, emulators run code written for A on B.

Comment: @Woeitg yes, because you can emulate everything.

Comment: @PeterMortensen please do not put console outputs into quotation tags, it is not monospaced and ruins the formatting.

Comment: Note that if you can't use deep learning code with your current version of matlab, you could also use an older version for this project.

Answer (score 1):

With R2016a, the ConvNet "functionality requires the Parallel Computing Toolbox™ and a CUDA®-enabled NVIDIA® GPU with compute capability 3.0 or higher."

See: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/nnet/convolutional-neural-networks.html

Comment: This is what I am aware of. The question is how to overcome this limitation

Answer (score -1):

The code example that you link to requires a GPU. As such the solution is very simple:

You need to use different code.

In your question it is not mentioned specifically what you are trying to achieve, so it is hard to say whether you would need to create something your self or will be able to pick up an exisiting solution, but this [CPU vs GPU deep learning benchmark](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/deep-learning-for-computer-vision-with-matlab-and-cudnn/) may be an inspiration.

Comment: Something that is good to know: A matlab license should allow you to run older versions of Matlab next to your existing one if needed.